# Error o verdad en Go, tipo de dato unit8 retorna un valor inseperado

Tags: funciones, algoritmos, backend, go, buenas-prácticas

La función "hola", es una función que retorna 2 valores, una es result y la otras es result - 100, el retorno de los valores se captura dentro de la función "main", en donde el primer valor es correcto mientras que el segundo es un valor inesperado, el cual no tengo conocimiento del valor o como llegó a ser ese valor.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var numeroPositivo uint8 = 15
    fmt.Println(numeroPositivo)
    dato1, dato2 := hola(1, 2)
    fmt.Printf("%d %d Numero", dato1, dato2)
}

func hola(x, y int8) (c, d int) {
    var result uint8 = 0
    result = uint8(x + y)
    return int(result), int(result - 100)
}
```

El resultado de la de la función con retorno es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De donde sale ese 159?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Un número entero de 8 bits **con signo** (`int8`) permite un rango entre -128 a 127

> Un número entero de 8 bits **sin signo** (`uint8`) permite un rango entre 0 a 255

En este caso la variable `result` es de tipo de dato `uint8`, lo cual permite un rango entre 0 a 255. Como el valor de esta variable es de 3, al restarse 100, no podrá tener un valor negativo. Omitirá el valor de -1 y empezara por 255. A partir de aquí seguirá restando.

- 3 - 4 = 255
- 255 - 96 (lo que queda por restar) = 159